# interactive map, how to create a link from a popup of a marker of the map to a template in symfony

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I am looking to make an interactive map. My map shows climbing sites in France for example. I want the popup of the marker of a map site to refer me to the template of this site which is descriptive. My project is in symfony. I proceeded as follows. In index.htmll.twig, I paste the map into a javascript tag. I try to loop on the variable 'sites' of the escalation sites in my database via the javascript script in the twig. but for the moment it does not work. Here is the code for the script in index.html.twig:

```
<script>
    //definiton de la variable site dans le script
    var site = {{sites}}

    //on initialise la carte
    var carte = L.map('macarte').setView([48.852969, 2.349903], 5);
    //on charge les tuiles
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            // Il est toujours bien de laisser le lien vers la source des données
            attribution: 'données © <a href="//osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>/ODbL - rendu <a href="//openstreetmap.fr">OSM France</a>',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 20
        }).addTo(carte);
    
     var icone = L.icon({
                iconUrl:"../img/pointeur-de-carte.png",
                iconSize: [50, 50],
                iconAnchor: [25, 50],
                popupAnchor: [-2, -44],
            });

    // on parcours les différents sites
               
    for ( site in sites) {
       
            // Nous définissons l'icône à utiliser pour le marqueur, sa taille affichée (iconSize), sa position (iconAnchor) et le décalage de son ancrage (popupAnchor) 
            //on crée un marqueur et on lui donne un popup
            var marqueur = L.marker([sites[site].lat, sites[site].lon],{icon:icone}).addTo(carte);
            //marqueur.bindPopup('<h3>sites</h3>');
            //marqueur.bindPopup(site);
                         
            marqueur.bindPopup(<a href="{{ path('site_show', {'id':sites.id}) }}">site</a>);

            
           // markerClusters.addLayer(marker); // Nous ajoutons le marqueur aux groupes
            //markerClusters.push(marqueur);
        }
                          
</script>
```

I have the following error:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").

The dump of sites in the twig is working. I don't know where to put an __toString to make the conversion to string work.

You can find too a picture of part of the DB.[image: DB]

And in the controller there's this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="site_index", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function index(SiteRepository $siteRepository): Response
{
    return $this->render('site/index.html.twig', [
        'sites' => $siteRepository->findAll(),
       
        
    ]);
}
```

Thank you.
Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part:

```
var site = {{sites}}
```

your `sites` is an array. You should serialize this variable first. You can do this with the new serialize filter in Symfony 5.3: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-twig-serialize-filter

```
var site = {{ sites|serialize('json') }}
```

If you're not using Symfony 5.3 yet, you should use the `json_encode` and `raw` filters:

```
var site = {{ sites|json_encode()|raw }}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tryed with var site = {{ sites|json_encode()|raw }} whitch worked. But it gave me another error: "Key "id" for array with keys "0, 1, 2" does not exist." In that case, it can't find the array, whitch doesn't exist anymore apprently. Somebody advised me to use the goejson from leaflet, you manage the geojson (probably on a list of variables, well it depends on how the back manages it), which you insert in the script tag. Still I have to do it...

Comment: But that's another question, right? You're not using the array in the code from your question.

Comment: I tryed to use the array with the 3 objects 0,1,2 whitch exist in the twig but not anymore when I loop in the script

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I've answered your question, but now you're asking a different question.

Comment: Thank you, you gave a good answer but I still can't ritch my goal. But I think I foun a solution, with you're help. I just have to work on it. Thank you again.